# How do I implement the ticker used in framer with framer motion?

Tags: javascript, framer-motion

```
               <AnimatePresence>
                    <ul className='AnimationLine'>
                        {
                            data.map((item) => (
                                <motion.li
                                    key={item.id}
                                    initial={{
                                        y: "100%",
                                        opacity: 0
                                    }}
                                    animate={{
                                        y: "-100%",
                                        opacity: 1
                                    }}
                                    exit={{
                                        y: "-100%",
                                        opacity: 0
                                    }}
                                    transition={{
                                        duration: 0.5,
                                        loop: Infinity,
                                        type: "ticker",
                                        speed: 1,
                                        // direction: "bottom",
                                        align: "center",
                                        gap: 10,
                                        padding: 10
                                    }}
                                    whileHover={{
                                        scale: isHovered
                                            ? 1.2
                                            : 0.5
                                    }}
                                    onHoverStart={() => setIsHovered(true)}
                                    onHoverEnd={() => setIsHovered(false)}>
                                    {item.name}
                                </motion.li>
                            ))
                        }
                    </ul>
                </AnimatePresence>
```

I've implemented it this way, but it doesn't loop properly. I ask for help. Thank you.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7em0x.png)

For your information, the attributes in Framer are the same as the image.

Answer (score 0):

This is in sveltekit but you can translate it into React easily, the principal is what matters.

```
// Script

const images = [
    '/images/1.jpeg',
    '/images/2.jpeg',
    '/images/3.jpeg',
    '/images/4.jpeg',
    '/images/5.jpeg'
];

let innerHeight: number;

// Svelte

<svelte:window bind:innerHeight />
<ul class='space-y-2'>
    {#each Array(2) as _} 
        {#each images as src}
            <Motion
                let:motion
                transition={{ duration: 5, ease: 'linear', repeat: Infinity }}
                initial={{ y: 0 }}
                animate={{ y: -innerHeight }}
            >
                <li use:motion>
                    <img {src} alt="image" class="rounded" />
                </li>
            </Motion>
        {/each}
    {/each}
</ul>
```

Essentially you have two stacks, they go in a loop from top to bottom (you can mess with direction, rate, etc). Once it gets to the end it loops back around. you have 2 stacks so once it gets to the bottom it looks seamless as it loops. Any questions feel free to ask. if you need it in React let me know. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. Pass in children, and make sure parent container has set width and height.

```
import React, {
  FC,
  useRef,
  useEffect,
  useState,
  MutableRefObject,
} from "react";
import { motion, useAnimation } from "framer-motion";
interface VC_TickerProps {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}

const VC_Ticker: FC<VC_TickerProps> = ({ children }) => {
  const controls1 = useAnimation();
  const controls2 = useAnimation();
  const ref1 = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);
  const ref2 = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);
  const speed = 200;
  const loop = (control: any, othersRef: MutableRefObject<HTMLDivElement>) => {
    const { left, width } = othersRef.current.getBoundingClientRect();
    const start = left - width - 80;
    control.set({ x: start });
    const duration = (window.innerWidth - start) / speed;
    control
      .start({
        x: window.innerWidth,
        transition: { duration: duration, ease: "linear" },
      })
      .then(() => {
        loop(control, othersRef);
      });
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    if (ref1.current && ref2.current) {
      const width = ref1.current.offsetWidth;

      const start1 = 0;
      const start2 = start1 - width - 80;
      controls1.set({ x: start1 });
      controls2.set({ x: start2 });

      const duration1 = (window.innerWidth - start1) / speed;
      const duration2 = (window.innerWidth - start2) / speed;
      controls1
        .start({
          x: window.innerWidth,
          transition: { duration: duration1, ease: "linear" },
        })
        .then(() => {
          loop(controls1, ref2 as MutableRefObject<HTMLDivElement>);
        });
      controls2
        .start({
          x: window.innerWidth,
          transition: { duration: duration2, ease: "linear" },
        })
        .then(() => {
          loop(controls2, ref1 as MutableRefObject<HTMLDivElement>);
        });
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        position: "relative",
        overflow: "hidden",
        whiteSpace: "nowrap",
        width: "100%",
        height: "100%",
      }}
    >
      <motion.div
        style={{ position: "absolute" }}
        ref={ref1}
        animate={controls1}
      >
        <div>{children}</div>
      </motion.div>
      <motion.div
        ref={ref2}
        style={{ position: "absolute" }}
        animate={controls2}
      >
        <div>{children}</div>
      </motion.div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default VC_Ticker;
```